# IO(Http) is cause the error "could not find implicit value for parameter system: akka.actor.ActorSystem"

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I am building a spray application in scala and I am following the example found [here](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.1/examples/spray-can/simple-http-server/src/main/scala/spray/examples/) but when I go to compile i get this error

```
Error:(38, 7) could not find implicit value for parameter system: akka.actor.ActorSystem
                IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(webServer,
                  ^
```

And google search have lead me no where, here is the code for my application

```
package au.net.hivemedia.polydeploy

import akka.actor.{Props, ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.io.IO
import au.net.hivemedia.polydeploy.dono.http.WebServerActor
import spray.can.Http

/**
 * PolyDeploy Dono - Braeburn
 *
 * Copyright (c) Hive Media Production, 2014.
 * All rights reserved. Do not redistribute
 *
 */
object App extends App {

  final val VERSION = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  final val CODENAME = "Twilight Sparkle"

  private var instance: Dono = _
  private var actorSystem: ActorSystem = _
  private var webServer: ActorRef = _

  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Starting PolyDeploy Dono v" + VERSION)
    println("=+ Project Version Codename: " + CODENAME)

    instance = new Dono()
    println("=+ Loading required items into the runtime")
    instance.load()

    println("=+ Loading new Actor System")
    actorSystem = ActorSystem("DonoActorSystem")

    println("=+ Starting web interface server")
    webServer = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[WebServerActor], name = "WebServer")

    IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(webServer,
                         interface = instance.getConfiguration().getString("web-bind-host"),
                         port = instance.getConfiguration().getInt("web-bind-port"))

  }
}
```

I can post more code snipits if required

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: `IO.apply` takes implicit `ActorSystem`. Either make `actorSystem` as implicit by using `implicit var actorSytem` or pass `actorSystem` explicitly as `IO(Http)(actorSystem)`

Comment: Thanks @mohit, that works swimmingly, if you add it as a answer I will tick it

Comment: Glad it was useful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IO.apply` takes an implicit `ActorSystem`. Either make `actorSystem` as implicit by using `implicit var actorSytem` or pass `actorSystem` explicitly as `IO(Http)(actorSystem)`

Comment: Looking back at that example code I can see right there it has `ActorSystem` as `implicit`. Just one of those things you don't see while coding late at night. But again, thanks! :D